# Access newLocation from the locationManager method from other ViewController's

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm using CoreLocation and am starting the locationManager from within my applications AppDelegate. Example Code below...

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...

    // start location manager
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        myLocationManager_ = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        myLocationManager_.delegate = self;
        [myLocationManager_ startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    else 
    {
        // ... rest of code snipped to keep this short
```

And in this method we see the updated location.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSString *currentLatitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSLog(@"AppDelegate says: latitude: %@", currentLatitude);

    // ... rest of code snipped
```

Now, within other areas of my application I need to determine the users current location (latitude, longitude). I could incorporate the code above into the ViewControllers that need current location but then I would have multiple instances of CLLocationManager running (I think) - and why duplicate this code?? Isn't there a way that, from other ViewControllers, I can just grab the location information from the AppDelegate?

PS - I'm using Xcode 4.3 w/ ARC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, declare the variable as a property in your appDelegate:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *array;`

(@synthesize in your .m too)

Then in your view controllers, create an appDelegate variable:

`AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

then you can do:
`NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.array);`

Comment: Ahh, what a beautiful thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Thank you mohabitar for answering this for me! For clarity sake I've posted my code for others to enjoy.

Note: Only relevant parts shown below.

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *myLocationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        currentLocation_ = [[CLLocation alloc] init];

        myLocationManager_ = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        myLocationManager_.delegate = self;
        [myLocationManager_ startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    currentLocation_ = newLocation;
}
```

Other ViewControllers.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentLocation;
```

Other ViewControllers.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        currentLocation_ = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:appDelegate.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:appDelegate.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }
}
```

Thanks again!